# Error While Using Multiprocessing Library in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-multiprocessing, python-logging

I am getting an error on Python when using the `Multiprocessing` library.

I have a list of 18,000 ids to collect via a `GET` from an external API (function `update_events()`) and then save each json file to blob storage in Azure . This would take a long time in a single-threaded environment so I decided to use a thread pool.

```
import logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

import json

from Multiprocessing import Pool

def update_events(id:int):
    try: 
        events = get_events(id) ### This is a GET to an external API
        file_name = str(id) + '.json'
        upsert_obj(file_name,'events',json.dumps(events))
    except Exception:
        LOGGER.error("Unable to write " + file_name + " to events folder")       


### This command writes the file to Azure Blob Storage
def upsert_obj(file_name: str, container_name: str, sb_data: dict):
    try:
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(
            container=PATH+"/"+str(container_name), blob=file_name)
        blob_client.upload_blob(sb_data, overwrite=True)
        LOGGER.info("Successfully upsert " +
                    file_name + " to " + container_name)
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.error(e)

## This is the multithreaded function 
def get_data_multithreaded(new_ids:list):
    with Pool(60) as p:
        p.map(update_events,new_ids)

def collect_data(new_events_ids):
    LOGGER.info('Starting collection...')
    start_time = time.time()
    get_data(new_events_ids)
    LOGGER.info("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

So I open `jupyter-notebook` and type the following:

```
new_ids= [1234,4567,6789] # just an example, many more ids in reality
collect_data [new_ids]
```

And it works for the most part. However, at some point during the collection I hit an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_name' referenced before assignment
```

As this is multi-threaded, I'm not very sure how or if I have error handled correctly. I'm also not sure if the error is coming from `update_events()` or `upsert_obj()`. As far as I know we are not hitting any rate limits on the API.

Comment: If this line `events = get_events(id)`, raises _any_ exception, what happens?

Comment: @Axe319 I tried doing a `raise Exception ('exception occured')` and it seemed to have triggered the same error as my question. What should I do to handle the API call?

Comment: You should initialize `file_name` before anything else. As it stands, any exception that `events = get_events(id)` raises will trigger the `except` clause which executes this line `LOGGER.error("Unable to write " + file_name + " to events folder")`. At that point, `file_name` is not yet defined because it never reached this line `file_name = str(id) + '.json'` and raises the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Axe319 for the solution, it looks like I need to initialize `file_name` before everything else, as in here:

```
def update_events(id:int):
    try: 
        ### Initialize first to ensure it's defined for error log
        file_name = str(id) + '.json'  

        ### If get_events errors out now, Exception will log properly
        events = get_events(id) 

        upsert_obj(file_name,'events',json.dumps(events))
    except Exception:
        LOGGER.error("Unable to write " + file_name + " to events folder")
```

I can confirm this fixed the initial issue after writing the logs to a text file. The multithreaded approach confused me at first but I think I understand now.